# Embedded youtube not working on IE8 and Windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, youtube, haml

I'm testing my website with Youtube embed with below code on IE8 and Windows XP:

This is in HAML on Rails

```
%object{height: "290", width: "500", type: "application/x-shockwave-flash", data: "http://www.youtube.com/v/#{@yt_youtube_id}&version=3&autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&fs=1"}
            %param{name: "movie", value: "http://www.youtube.com/v/#{@yt_youtube_id}&version=3&autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&fs=1"}/
            %param{name: "allowFullScreen", value: "true"}/
            %param{name: "allowscriptaccess", value: "always"}/
            %embed{allowfullscreen: "true", allowscriptaccess: "always", frameborder: "0", height: "290", src: "http://www.youtube.com/v/#{@yt_youtube_id}&version=3&autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&fs=1", width: "500"}
```

The above works fine on other browsers and IE9 and above.

What could be changed here so we can support IE8 on Windows XP without Youtube player throwing errors?

Comment: http://theie8countdown.com/

Comment: @apneadiving I hate IE8 but I hate Windows XP and IE8 combination even more!!!